# How to wire this delay relay switch

Tags: relay, timer, delay

Hello I recently bought [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/261876710970) item at ebay and I am not sure how I should wire this.

I will power it with a 9 volt battery and the relay will power a pump, [this](https://gyazo.com/198f5c9037d74d5308bbc1bbfa807284) is how they at ebay show how I should wire it. But I don't understand how I will connect my pump's positive and negative wires to the circuit or how I will connect my 9 volt battery to the circuit?

Since the (X) symbol on the chart is only powered by a negative wire from what i can understand. DC-

and from my basic knowledge the (x) symbol is a lamp? (the source that needs power)

I also don't understand what the two power terminal at the top will do that has nothing connected to it?

What this circuit will do is that it will delay my push button action so the power will remain on to the pump for 5 seconds then turn of instead of the push button will only power while pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relay is rated 12V DC, so I am not sure if it will turn on if you use 9V DC. There is nothing stated in [its datasheet](http://www.mycomkits.com/reference/Songle_SRD%28T73%29_Relay.pdf) about minimum voltage to turn on the relay. You may try, but nothing guarranteed.

[The picture](https://gyazo.com/198f5c9037d74d5308bbc1bbfa807284) that they give is wrong. The lamp (X) does not have power supply connected to it. It will never turn on.

I found [this picture](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=244105.0;attach=83655) and it may help you. The picture is FC-31 model but I think it has same wiring with FC-32 model.

The relay has normally open and normally close contact. To control a load (a lamp or a pump), we should connect the wire to normally open contact. Please look at this picture:
[image: relay wiring diagram]

Make sure to remove s5 jumper. 
I suggest you try with low voltage first, for example, using the same battery (9v) to control a DC lamp or a LED with 560 Ohm resistor in series. Then try to adjust s1, s2, and s4 jumper to get the suitable timer. If everything okay, you can proceed with high voltage and a pump.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to have to trigger the input and start the cycle as soon as the power is connected, I added a 0.22 microfarad capacitor in parallel with 2.2 meg to the momentary input.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got this on my bench.

**Note it works by OPENING the button circuit.**

Behavior:

Supply Voltage in, while Trigger jumpers open ->> Relay coil powered

Supply Voltage in, while Trigger shorted->> Relay not powered

When Trigger loop is opened ->> Relay not powered for the time set, forced - shorting the loop does not interfere.

I don't know what this is designed for, the possibility to set very short times make no sense.

Answer (score -2):

[image: FC-32 diagram]

These diagrams came with the circuit

[image]